# Stop certain users accessing C:\Source by security group

Tags: security, permissions, filesystems, network-share

We have a security group called SourceCode which allows certain users access to the SVN / GIT repository. This allows them to get the latest repo and store it in C:\Source. This works fine but the problem is that if a user who isn't in the SourceCode group logs onto a machine where the repo exists, they can see the C:\Source folder.

Is there a way I can stop users outside of SourceCode accessing C:\Source on ANY computer they log into?

We are using Windows SBS 2011 and everyone logs in via the domain.

Comment: 1. Is the Source folder on the server or on every computer? 2. Set the NTFS permissions on the Source folder so that only members of the SourceCode security group have access.

Comment: 1. `C:\SourceCode` will be on every computer that `SourceCode` users use but it will always be called `C:\SourceCode`. 2. I understand I can do this but can I do it via a group policy or something so it automatically applies to ALL machines without me having to go around each one?

Comment: Why would it be on every computer?  What for do you expect to happen if the user simply boots off a livecd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the appropriate NTFS permissions on the folder for all computers by using Group Policy. You'll do this by configuring the folder in your GPO at:

Computer Configuration | Windows Settings | Security Settings | File System